# Hidden dot underscore ._ before name of image files in a directory while reading them using glob

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, jpeg, glob

I am trying to read images from a directory.
The directory has images named like-

```
person1_bacteria_1.jpeg
person1_bacteria_2.jpeg
person2_bacteria_3.jpeg
```

I am trying to grab these images using glob function.

```
images = images_directory.glob('*.jpeg')
```

The problem is, while I print the directory of the files I have just read, I found that some of the files have dot underscore (._) before them.

For example-

```
dir/._person1_bacteria_2.jpeg
```

I checked the image files in the directory again and again but there was no image name with ._ before it.

How do I avoid reading files whose name have dot underscore (._) before it?

I am running this in an windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this files are just thumbnail files. if you look with os.path.getsize(filename) you can probably confirm this hypothesis.

The reason you don't see this files is that they are probably marked as hidden files. 
Try to configure your windows explorer such, that it shows all files. ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files )

Answer (score 1):

If `glob.glob` produces results with unexpected filenames, you can filter them with the following code using a comprehension list with a condition filter

```
import os
import glob
images = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '*.jpeg'))
images = [image for image in images if not os.path.basename(image).startswith('._')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the directory contains files starting with dot glob [won’t be matched by default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob). globe returns a list, you can write this code to add both normal files and hidden ones:

```
import glob
images = glob.glob('*.jpeg') + glob.glob('.*.jpeg')
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to exclude files that starts with `._` you can use this pattern:

```
images = glob.glob("[!._]*.jpeg")
```

Comment: What do I do if I want to avoid reading files whose names start with dot underscore (._) ?

Comment: @ShifatEArman you can use `[!._]*.jpeg`. See my updated answer

Comment: In fact this works very probably in your case, though you exclude theoretically a little more if you use `glob.glob("[^._]*.jpeg")`.
If you wanted to exclude files starting with `._` **but** to include files starting with `_.` it wouldn't work, it would exclude both